# getline() function behaves strangely

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to emulate telnet functionality by writing a socket listener program, and an application redirecting its console to the listener over sockets.

On the server side I opened a socket on my local ip, a defined port, and started listening on it like this

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr);
listen(sockfd,5);
neewsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clien);
```

Then I started reading the incoming data in a separate thread like this:

```
while(1)
{
  bzero(buffer,256);
  n= read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
  if(n>0)
     printf("%s",buffer);
}
```

And in the main routine after the listening code I added the socket data sending part like this.

```
while(1)
{
   bzero(buffer,256);
   getline(&buffer,&t,stdin);
   n=send(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),MSG_EOR);
}
```

And for the client part I had connected to the server like this.

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AfF_INET,hostip,&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr)
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
connect(sockfd,serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
```

And then I duped the stdin, stdout and stderr to sockfd descriptor for redirecting the console as follows.

```
 dup2(sockfd,STDIN_FILENO);
 dup2(sockfd,STDOUT_FILENO);
 dup2(sockfd,STDERR_FILENO);

 close(sockfd);
```

And finally I have something like this in the client to test the console redirecting

```
while(1)
{
   bzero(mystring,256);
   i = getline(&string,&t,stdin);
   printf("Input:%s-%d\n",mystring,i);
}
```

In the above code I expect the getline to be blocked until I enter some characters on the server application console, but for my agony it comes out with value 0 repeatedly.

Any idea why this behavior?

Comment: is getline(&string,&t,stdin) a typo in your question? you initialize mystring, you try to print mystring but you "getline" in string ...

Comment: yes it was a typo, it should be mystring instead

Comment: yes the corrected code is this                                                      while(1)
{
   bzero(mystring,256);
   i = getline(&mystring,&t,stdin);
   printf("Input:%s-%d\n",mystring,i);
}

Comment: I assume you are checking all of these calls (connect, send, etc.) to see if they return -1?  I would start by using `lsof` on each process to make sure the file descriptors actually are open socket connections like you expect them to be.

Comment: this is just the code snippet for understanding the problem, in my real program I do check all the error returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing sockets with [`stdio(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is a bad idea<sup>TM</sup>. Both `stdin` and `stdout` are *line-buffered*, see [`setbuf(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html), and that's probably what gets you here. There's also a matter of thread-safety - `stdio` streams are locked, but since you already use GNU extensions you can try their [unlocked](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html) counterparts.

#### Edit 0:

Based on your input in the comments, I think this would be the solution:

- create a [`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) in the parent process before doing `fork(2)`
- in the chaild process [`dup2(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup.2.html) the pipe's read file descriptor into `STDIN` after the `fork(2)` but before the `execve(2)`
- in the newly `exec`-ed child process just read the standard input
- in the parent process *copy* the standard input into the write file descriptor of the pipe.

This should avoid most of the confusion.

Comment: Mixing sockets with stdio is not that bad if a new `FILE` objects are created from them via fdopen(), but replacing file descriptors of already opened files and buffered files (as `stdin` and `stdout`) could not work reliably.

Comment: my requirement is to do console interactions with the run time launched process.As newly launched process's stdio is also pointing to the current process stdio it becomes difficult to interact with both processes. So many had suggested this descriptors replacing approach for this problem.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean here, but it looks like you'd want to explore `select(2)` and `poll(2)` family of functions for I/O multiplexing.

Comment: What I wanted is, my scanf and other stdin functions to accept input from both the processes. As both the processes(one process launched from other) will be pointing to the same console it wont possible to give inputs to different applications through the same console isn't it? And if select(2) and poll(2) can be used for my problem can you elaborate more on that.

Comment: Could you update the question with some description of the process hierarchy and how you want them to interact? I sort of confused about what you are doing.

Comment: all I do is run an application app1 from command line like #./app1 this application will internally call exec flavored functions to launch app2. Now app1 also does some scanf's as does app2. Given this situation it becomes quit messy on the console with regards to interaction with the apps. So I want to have the other app send its out put another console on which I am listen for. Does this make things clear?

Comment: If it's a terminal (console), you won't get any input into the second app - first app is in control of the terminal. If `stdin` is a file or a socket, you'd get unpredictable results that would depend on how OS is scheduling the processes.

Comment: ya its terminal and exactly thats my problem I am trying to address here getting the input in to the second applications.thats where are i am using this server application in my above post to do that job for me.

Comment: Nikolai,                                                                      Thanks for patiently following and my messages and replying them. My requirement is little bit more complex than just launching two process there will be nested launching starting from parent process to child...to grand child and so on. So pipe is not a sufficient enough solution for my problem. I gave up on programming my self such application instead I am thinking to use netcat which does the functionaly that I need.                                                                        Thanks again.

Comment: @venkat, it looks like you are over-complicating things. Try to focus on the simplest solution. Good luck anyway.